# Why are electrons in one atom attracted to negative electrons in another atom?

Tags: energy

Why or for what purpose is this attraction purposeful or what is the reasoning behind why these energy particles are drawn to each other?

Any proven results, or proposed theories of your own, or other ideas why?

I don't mean this from a practical standing point of convenience (i.e, I don't mean why are they in correlation of electrical use, but just "why" in general are they attracted).

EXAMPLE: Why would lesser electrons make one atom want to draw more? Why does the atom, to be blunt, need or have any purpose to draw/attract other energy, vice-versa, etc.?

Comment: The *electric force* is just something that is observed in nature, given a name, studied and modelled mathematically.

Comment: this is not really a physics question. physics can only answer "how" questions: based on a few axioms and postulates one explains how  atoms which are electrically neutral have stable bonds to other atoms. the answer to "why" these axioms, is "because" the observations can be described; circular.

Comment: Besides what anna mentions, this question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the way you're imagining this is the source of your confusion.  Electrons in one atom are not attracted to the electrons in another atom.  What actually happens is that it requires less energy for two atoms to come together and share some electrons in a [covalent bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond).  How much can be saved and the configuration of the bonded atoms depends on the configuration of their electrons and especially the outer valence electrons.

There was a [question similar to this at Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/710/fundamental-forces-behind-covalent-bonding/).

If you want to dive deep into the details, see the [electronegativity Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity).